# Best / Most Secure Way to Pass Javascript Variables Between Websites without PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, variables, cookies

### The Problem:

Hello, suppose i have two websites that I own.

Site.com and Site.com:3000.

There are many ways to pass variables between these two.

I can not use localstorage (two different domains), but i can pass variables in links and etc.

The only problem is that these ways are not secure.

The most secure way is _SESSION, but unfortunately only one of my websites can use PHP(site.com).

What is the most secure way to pass variables between sites without using PHP?

---

### The Parameters:

I do not want it to be possible for users to tamper with the variables because it can really ruin the purpose of the website.

I need to transfer the variables while redirecting to the next site.

---

### Conclusion:

I am decent at JS, but not a master, so please be descriptive in your answers.

Thanks!

Comment: Is ti simply transferring a user from one to the other? or do users flop back and forth?  If a simple transfer, send a POST request via curl, store in db, and return a token.  Redirect client, using token in URL as get arg, retrieve info from db, regenerate session

Comment: Sorry i'm not a master at php, could you write an answer with code examples and etc? I only need to send variables from site.com:3000 to site.com. Site.com:3000 does not have php

Answer (score 0):

Do the two domains have commonality in the base domain (e.g. foo.example.com and bar.example.com)? If yes, you can set the domain of the cookie as the higher level domain (example.com).

Comment: yeah so my first domain for example is stackoverflow.com/page.php and the other is stackoverflow.com:3000.

Comment: Cookies have the option to have the domain set. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie  -- if it's common and the site presents under the domain, the cookie will be visible

Comment: But how do i get the cookie or create it if site.com:3000 does not have php functionality?

Comment: cookies, unless sneaky marked  are readable and assignable from JavaScript: `document.cookie`